# How to retrieve serial number of a cert from a JKS file programmatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, ssl-certificate, keystore

**Given** :
path to JKS,
password for the JKS,
alias of the cert

how can I get the serial number of the cert from the JKS, programmatically ?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a certificate from a Java keystore like that:

```
      char[] pwdArray = "password".toCharArray();
      KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      ks.load(new FileInputStream("myKeyStore.jks"), pwdArray);
      Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("MyAlias");
```

The base Certificate class has no method to access serial numbers, but I assume that you are using X.509 certificates. The you can use the X509Certificate class like that:

```
      X509Certificate xcert = (X509Certificate) cert;
      BigInteger serial = xcert.getSerialNumber();
```

You can see details in the API docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html